# requires vibrate permission although permission is in manifest

Tags: java, android, permissions

I want to make my device vibrate on tapping on a button. But it always throws me the `java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission` error although I have the VIBRATE permission in the manifest.

I know that from API 23 the apps have to ask on runtime for some permissions but according to [this link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) the Vibrate permission is granted without having to ask.

Any Ideas?

Method code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            return true;

        case R.id.share:
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...
            return true;
        case R.id.sync:
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            v.vibrate(500); //MainActivity line 832
            getRemoteItems();

        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pigmalionstudios.todolist">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

**EDIT:**
Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.pigmalionstudios.todolist, PID: 3380
              java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
                  at android.os.IVibratorService$Stub$Proxy.vibrate(IVibratorService.java:163)
                  at android.os.SystemVibrator.vibrate(SystemVibrator.java:77)
                  at android.os.Vibrator.vibrate(Vibrator.java:178)
                  at android.os.Vibrator.vibrate(Vibrator.java:97)
                  at android.os.Vibrator.vibrate(Vibrator.java:76)
                  at com.pigmalionstudios.todolist.Activities.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:832) //This line of code is v.vibrate(500);
                  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3450)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:368)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
                  at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:65)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:202)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:780)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:624)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:150)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire Java stack trace?

Comment: Put it. @CommonsWare

Comment: OK, that's fairly straightforward. What device are you testing on? I just created a scrap project that uses `vibrate()` in `onOptionsItemSelected()`, with the `VIBRATE` permission, and it works just fine on a Nexus 9 running Android 7.1.1.

Comment: I am using a LG Nexus 5X with Android 8.1.0

Comment: Are you using Instant Run?

Comment: Is this really the manifest that ends up in your APK? Double check the merged manifest under your app's `build/intermediates/manifests/full/...`

Comment: @dazza5000 No, I even uninstalled the app several times but it continues with the same error.

Comment: OK, I tried my scrap project on a Nexus 5X with Android 8.1, and it works fine. I'm with laalto -- your manifest may not contain what you think it does.

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I check what ends up on the Nexus manifest?

Comment: Quoting myself from [a recent blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/02/06/vet-your-manifest.html): "Use the “Merged Manifest” sub-tab of the manifest editor in Android Studio, to see what is going into the manifest from all sources. Double-check that with [the APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html), to see the contents of the manifest in your production APK."

Comment: @CommonsWare Great article in your blog! Ok, here is what I did: I opened the MergedManifest and checked if the permission is there and it was. Then I analyzed my APK and checked the manifest and the vibrate permission was there, too. Then I ran my app and it broke right away on runtime. I uninstalled it and installed it again and now it vibrates, but I did not change anything. I suppose by opening one of those two manifests it did some sort of  "manifest refresh" and now it works. Thanks, I learned a lot here!

Answer (score 8):

I just met the same issue. The way to fix it is rebuild your app.

Changing code will cause react native refresh your app, but seems it won't reload your AndroidManifest.xml.

Thus, just manually run `react-native run-android` again.